# how to launch native map application in winRT xaml app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

what i want is to launch native map application on button click in my winRT application using C# and XAML. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you tried anything? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779672.aspx) is the key, [LaunchURIAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) is the API.

Take a look at the [Association Launching sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec) for code, and for maps in particular here is the [URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx) that shows how you can launch the app into various different modes and experiences.