# Open Camera Application From My App in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Is there any way to open Windows 8.1 native camera application programatically in c#.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Have a look at this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809572/how-to-launch-native-map-application-in-winrt-xaml-app

Answer (score 1):

Basically `WinRT` doesn't allow that, Metro Apps run in the highly sandboxed environment, you can't open a a Metro nor a desktop one directly, you may find using the [Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241801.aspx) class from Windows.System.Launcher somehow helpful , take a look at this thread :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b38bb2de-2a05-4f7d-8547-48b9759d72d4/can-i-use-windowssystemlauncherlauncherdefaultprogramuri-to-invoke-another-metro-style-app?forum=winappswithhtml5